# TypeError: 'int' object has no attribute '__getitem__' in python

Tags: python, oop, runtime-error, typeerror

I've been trying to make a easy Object Oriented game for console. Initially, this game gonna create a list that created by the random numbers between 0 and 9. Length of that list is gonna be 5 but it sometimes can be 4 because if list contains 0 more than one it's deleting automatically. After that this is gonna put 0 to a index after some calculations for where to insert 0. Program is gonna get the first index of the variable that will be calculated for where to put 0 but sometimes first index might be more than my length of list. For this, I created a variable named IndexOfZero and I have setted this equal to  first index of the variable that calculated where to put 0.
After I've done that I'm getting this error called TypeError: 'int' object has no attribute '**getitem**' How can i fix this?

```
def PutZero(self, x='t'):

    elements = 0
    element = []
    putZero = 0

    for x in range(len(self.list)):
        elements += self.list[x]
        element.append(elements)

    sum = element[-1]
    print(sum,'This is the sum.')

    if self.list.count(0) == 0:
        putZero = (math.sqrt(math.pow(random.randrange(50,100), 5) / sum + self.list[2]) )
        putZero = int(math.floor(putZero))

    IndexOfZero = putZero[0] """the line that I'm getting error"""

    if IndexOfZero == 0:
        IndexOfZero = random.randrange(0,3)
        print(IndexOfZero,'Randomly generated value')

    if IndexOfZero > 5 or IndexOfZero > 4:"""Do I still get the same error for this line and for the below ?"""
        IndexOfZero = random.randrange(0,3)

    if x:
        return '{}'.format(self.list)
```

---

Error is this :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File
"/home/guney/Find_Zer0/Code.py", line 52, in PutZero
IndexOfZero = putZero[0]
TypeError: 'int' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

Comment: `putZero` is a number. What are you expecting `putZero[0]` to do? `0[0]` for example doesn't make any sense.

Comment: `putZero` is an `int`, you can't subscript an `int`, e.g. `1[0]` is an error - what are you trying to accomplish - did you simply mean `IndexOfZero = putZero`?

Comment: @AChampion I mean IndexOfZero is equal to first value of putZero variable. If the way I'm trying to do is not true how can I do this? my goal is this program to make calculations in putZero variable and then setting this variables first value equal to IndexOfZero variable. for example the result of putZero is gonna be like : 781245 and I want to get the first element which is 7 and setting this equal to IndexOfZero And checking Is it bigger than 4 or 5, Changing the value according to result.

Comment: @Carcigenicate I saw it in some tutorials they were creating a int variable and when they say something like print( integerValue[0])  the first figure of the number was printing I wanted to do that. I tell other things on the comment section you can read it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you can't index a number. I think you were misunderstanding the tutorial you were using, or the tutorial isn't reliable.

If you want to get the first digit of a number, you could either use math, or turn it into a string first.

Since you're using indexing, you seem to be trying to do the second way.

Here's an example of how to do this:

```
num = 1234
str_num = str(num)
first_char = str_num[0] # Get the first character of the string
first_digit = int(first_char) # Parse the string as an integer

print(first_digit) # Prints the number 1
```

This way is slower than using straight math, but in most cases that shouldn't be a problem.